# SQL - Aggregate Sales vs Specific Inventory

Tags: sql, oracle

| date | week | calendar_st_week | calendar_end_week | sales | inventory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-06 | 14 | 2021-04-05 | 2021-04-11 | 2 | 12 |

I have a table with above schema in Oracle SQL. I'd like to aggregate daily sales to a week level between `calendar_st_week` and `calendar_end_week` and then compare it to the inventory on `calendar_end_week`. How would you compare aggregate sales to inventory on a specific date (i.e., row) in SQL?

Hoping to get a final table like this:

| week | calendar_st_week | calendar_end_week | total sales per week | inventory at the end of the week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 2021-04-05 | 2021-04-11 | 7 | 10 |

Comment: `LAST_VALUE()`? Please speficy which database are you using.

Comment: Is this a school problem? I would suggest you need to try and provide a solution and then we can help fix the solution. BTW, this does not provide near enough information to attempt a solution. At a minimum both table structure would be needed.

Comment: Use a CTE to get your aggregate value by week. What's not clear is are you trying to show this aggregate at the week level but show at a date level? So, all days in week 14 would have the same aggregate value? Sample of data and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: sum(sales) over (partition by week)

Comment: keeping both 'calendar_start_week' and 'calander_end_week'  is a design flaw.  If you know one, you can - and should - just calculate the other at run time.  What prevents one from being incorrect in relation to the other.   Second, your basic question seems to assume that no new inventory ever arrives.

Comment: A table doesn't "have a schema", a schema has tables.